# Using R-selenium to scrape data from an aspx webpage

Tags: html, asp.net, r, selenium

I am pretty new to r and selenium so hopefully i can express myself clearly about my question. 
I want to scrape some data off a website (.aspx) and i need to type some chemical code to be able to pull out some information in the next page (using R-selenium to input and click element). So far i have been able to build a short code that will get me through the first step, i.e. pull out the correct page i wanted. But i had so much trouble in finding a good way to scrape the data (the chemical information in the table) off this website. Mainly because the website will not assign a new html address instead of give me the same aspx address for any chemical i search. I plan to overcome this and then build a loop so i can scrape more information automatically. Anyone has any good thoughts that how i should get the data off after click-element? I need the chemical information table in the second page. 
Thanks heaps in advance!

Here i put my code that i wrote so far: the next step i need is to scrape the table out the next page!

```
library("RSelenium")
checkForServer()
startServer()
mybrowser <- remoteDriver()
mybrowser$open()
mybrowser$navigate("http://limitvalue.ifa.dguv.de/")
mybrowser$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#Tbox_cas")
wxbox <- mybrowser$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#Tbox_cas")
wxbox$sendKeysToElement(list("64-19-7"))
wxbutton <- mybrowser$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#Butsearch")
wxbutton$clickElement()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your tool choice is wrong.

Secondly, in your case

1. POST to the "permanent" url
2. 302 redirect to a new url, which is http://limitvalue.ifa.dguv.de/WebForm_ueliste2.aspx in your case
3. GET the new url

Thirdly, what's the ultimate output you are after?

It really depends on how much data you are up to. Otherwise do a manual task.